# Probability that two people sit next to each other within a round table?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

> Six friends named Ankit, Balwinder, Chandra, Dayaram, Eskil, and Fred are sitting at a round table with six chairs.

What is the probability Chandra and Fred sit next to each other?

The heard the answer is $5!*2/6!=1/3$ but I am not sure.

Pretend that Chandra and Fred are one person and then multiply by two because CF=FC, next divide by six factorial because we have to divide by the total possibilities.

I do not really understand why we multiply the factorial of five by two rather than do $(5!+1)/6!$ because FC and CF only increase the numerator by one.

Comment: Fred is equally likely to be in any of the 5 chairs Chandra is not sitting in. Two of those are next to her.

Comment: The answer you heard is incorrect.  If you do not understand the answers to the linked question, let me know.